# what hooks are recommended in react native (or react) in complex component structure (i have redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

[image]

for example my component tree structure likes the picture,i want to implement that when i press component B's button (or touchable..), i want to change component A's color or shape.
this is terrible when i use only props and useState.
you can recommend other external libraries.
i have been using redux but not working because when i touch B, A is not re-rendered.
can you suggest a way or hooks or libraries?

Comment: Why is A not being re-rendered when you click the button in B if you are using redux? Sounds like you have a bug there

Comment: Try to use useEffect hook to triger rerender when component state changes.

Comment: Using `useSelector` in component A should work with redux. If dispatching an action in component B changes state that is accessed by A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answer my question. it is just my mistake of redux so state is not changed.
I don't keep vaild data format.
I fix my data appropriately, it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a complex react app too with a similar component tree.
I think the Redux approach is relevant.

Touching B should update the redux state
Then a `useEffect` hook placed in component A should take the Redux state as dependency in order to trigger the effect.

Something like that :

(the redux part can differ depending on the version)

```
const CompB = () => {
    function sayHelloToCompA() {
        useDispatch(updateReduxState('Hello compA')) // triggers redux action that will update redux state
    }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.button} 
            onPress={() => sayHelloToCompA()>
                <Text>Press me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Once Redux state is updated, then :

```
const CompA = () => {
    const { messageFromCompB } = useSelector(state => state.yourReduxSlice) 
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(messageFromCompB)
    }, [messageFromCompB]);  
            
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: The important part would be actually using `messageFromCompB` in the rendered markup, the `useEffect` is just for debugging and not actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might use any state management library out there (such as Redux or MobX), but in a relatively simple case (in which your state isn't that complex), you can use [React.Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) whose purpose is precisely to avoid [Prop Drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) and allow unrelated trees to share information (as long as this information is provided by a common ancestor).